# How to find combination of 65 objects with 2 "states" for each object?

Tags: combinatorics

I have a problem in which I need to find the combination involving three tables or whether or not the table has a student working in it or not. If I am not mistaken, order doesn't matter, therefore I just listed out all combinations and found 8 combinations. However, this would take too much time for I need to do the same with 65 tables for ex.

Is there a formula to calculate the combination?

Comment: Start small (like you have, but also try with $1$ table and $2$ tables). See if you can recognize a pattern.

Comment: this is similar to flipping a coin (student or not). One flip of a coin - one table.

Comment: @Clayton, I found that each addition of an extra table is 2x from before, so I assumed the formula is f(n) = 2^n

Comment: That’s right! So you have evidence for the pattern and have recognized the formula; can you prove it?

Comment: I think I could by counting out combinations for one n variable and then test it using the formula, anyway, thank you for helping me!